# Prove that for all sets A and B, A ⊆ A∪B.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A = A\cup B$ be true, it suficces that $B=\emptyset$, but, as we observe ,we are trying to prove $A\subseteq A\cup B$ for arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$. Should $B=\emptyset$, then we are stating that any arbitrary sets is empty, which contradicts the axiom of existence: "There exists a set with no elements".

Since we know $A=A\cup B$ is not true for all sets $A$ and $B, A\subseteq A\cup B$ must be true. That being so, $A\subseteq A\cup B$
is trivially true.

Is this proof right?

Comment: How does the fact that $A=A\cup B$ is not always true prove that $A\subset A\cup B$ must be true?

Comment: Can you recite the definition of $X \subseteq Y$?

Comment: Well, since one of those cases must be true and the other one false. I thought that if I already knew which one was false then the other must me true and then the disjunction holds.

Comment: A note: When someone has adequately answered your question, it's helpful to mark the answer ask accepted (i.e. click the check-mark).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the sign $\subseteq$ in a very inefficient way, and making things more complicated than necessary!

Yes for inequalities like $X\le Y$, it means $X=Y$ or $X<Y$. Similary, $A\subseteq B$ means "$A=B$" or "$A$ is a proper subset of $B$", i.e., $A\subsetneq B$. But you don't need this!

Simply go with the **definition**: $P\subseteq Q$ means *any* element in $P$ is an element in $Q$.

So, is any element in $A$ an element in $A\cup B$? Of course, being in $A\cup B$ means either in $A$ or either in $B$.

QED.

Comment: I don't want to seem hard-headed but, does that mean my attempt of proof is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but your attempt is incorrect.

Comment: I understand. The reason why I say it's false is also wrong?

Comment: You confused yourself. **If** you already know that $P\subseteq Q$ is true, then either $P=Q$ or $P\subsetneq Q$. But this is what you want to prove, not an assumption.